# Repaint on scroll when using overflow:auto and border-radius

Tags: html, css, performance

When using overflow: auto on an element, I am noticing a performance issue. I have tried translateZ(0) and backface-visibility: hidden but neither solved the issue.

```
<div id="testA">
  <ul>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 12em;
  background: #c6c6c6;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}

#testA ul {
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  height: 6em;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is actually caused by the border-radius. Having overflow: auto or overflow: scroll on an element which has a border-radius causes paint storms and to repaint on scroll.

It would be suggested to remove the border-radius from such elements completely.

Demo: http://codepen.io/kevinfarrugia/pen/KgAYyE

CSS:

```
#testB .container {
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

#testB ul {
  height: 6em;
  overflow: auto;  
}
```